# Vertical and horizontal align of image

Tags: html, css, image, alignment

I have a placeholder (under construction) site which holds only one image with the logo. I horizontically aligned with margin: 0 auto.
But how do I know additionally horizontal align the image.
Or with one sentence: How do I fully centrate an image.

[Look here to see live: fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/egxa2/)

Regards,
Bodo

EDIT:
For 1:2 (height to width) images use:

```
#wrapper img
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 799px;
    height: 404px;
    margin: -202px -399px 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

like in the linked thread :)

thank you for the help

Comment: please post your code on http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Urm.. Have you tried ?

```
<div class='placeholder'>
   <img src='../images/myimage'>
</div>
```

And the css for that markup

```
.placeholder
{
position : absolute;
top : 50%;
left : 50%;
width : 200px; /* Width of the image in question */
height : 200px;/* height of the image in question */
margin : -100px 0px 0px -100px;
}
```

This should bring your image to the very center of the page.

Comment: Hi, this works for squares with a height to width from 1:1 my image has 1:2 (you can't know this...). I fiddled the result see the opening post

Answer (score 1):

This will do it

```
img#logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: -50px;
    margin-top: -50px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DxByM/

Comment: Hi, this works for squares with a height to width from 1:1 my image has 1:2 (you can't know this...). I fiddled the result see the opening post

Comment: Just change width, height and margins to suit, margin-left should be half the width, margin-top should be half the height.

Answer (score 0):

Have a div to hold the image with the following rules:

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top:200px;  <!-- Will depend on your image -->
width:[your-image-width]px;
```

Will center your image

Comment: Only horizontally. The OP wants vertical as well; see title.

Comment: My bad. See the edit. This will do what he wants, will just need to fiddle with the margin top rule accordingly.