# Grid CSS, Image inside fixed-size div, keep aspect ratio using css-only

Tags: css, image, grid

I have a grid of fixed size divs, and this must remain CSS-only.
Inside each div, I have a random size image inside.

I need the image to scale to the div size while keeping the aspect ratio, and also be centered both horizontally and vertically within the div.

```
  #holder {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .tile {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    /*vertical-align: middle;*/
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
  }
  .tile img {
    /*vertical-align: middle;*/
    outline: 1px dashed red;
    max-height:100%;
    max-width:100%;
  }
```

Can't center vertically. Everything else seems to work fine.

UPDATE: Also this doesn't work when the img is smaller than the div.

Comment: Show us the code you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

`width: 100%;` and `height: auto;` (or `height: auto !important;` in case there is a height attribute on the img element) usually does the trick.

Sorry misread the question, this fixes the aspect ratio but not the centering. [This tread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10515252/vertical-and-horizontal-align-of-image) might give some valuable ideas.

Comment: This would work if I didn't have a height set for the div. When the image has long height (portrait), using this makes the image jump out of the div.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I have solved that using `overflow: hidden;` in the past, but that's not a very good solution since it "crops" the image. It might prevent breaking the layout though.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the block height is unknown.

Here's a solution that work on firefox/chrome:

```
#holder {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.tile {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    display: table;
}
.tile-layout {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.tile img {
    outline: 1px dashed red;
    width:100%;
}
```

Using this html template:

```
 <div id="holder">
      <div class="tile">
           <div class="tile-layout">
                <img src="{{ img }}"/>
           </div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Test in Chrome reveals tile height gets ignored using this styling. Also, it ignores the grid, all tiles form a single column.

I've found a solution using overflow: auto, float: left and position: absolute. I still couldn't fix the vertical alignment.

Answer (score 0):

```
#holder {

    display:table;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height:100%;
    possition:relative;

}

.tile {

    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;

}

.tileInner{

    display:block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    padding: 10px 15px;

}

.tile img {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    outline: 1px dashed red;
    max-height:100%;
    max-width:100%;

}
```

html

```
<div id="holder">

    <div class="tile">

        <div class="tileInner">

                <img src="imageUrl"/>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```